# Is it implied that the "tards" are actually above normal?

Tags: idiocracy

[When Joe meets with Dr Lexus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BdPmNM0IF7Y) the good doctor indicates that he is a "tard" and reassures his patient that his first wife is also one and she is okay -- in fact, she works as a pilot.

While Joe's performance of the test he is later given indicates that he is the most intelligent man alive (although we know he is completely average for our own time) is it possible that occasionally people as bright or brighter than Joe are born in the 26th century and are given the more demanding jobs (such a pilot) but that perhaps due to the way the tests are calibrated, they show up as retarded and are ignored? This would explain why no "tard" is asked how to deal with the crises facing the world of 2505.

I don't really think there is a good way to explain why Joe is a special case and brought to the attention of the President; my question is really whether bright people are occasionally born and that they somehow are shunted to the important jobs.

Note that by "above normal" I mean for our time even -- of course some people in 2505 would be above the normal for their own time. Probably the President and even some of his cabinet are examples of that. (Although that does not mean they are as bright as average for our time.)

Note: If there really are, as in Kornbluth, a small percentage of geniuses (not sure how to deal with the billions of dumb and at least in Idiocracy, dangerous people) then the crop crisis might have arisen despite the geniuses -- people were worried about their stock price or whatever or the company was just too powerful and the bright humans thought their lives were imperiled (or maybe those who spoke up got rehabilitated). If the movie were not clearly not meant to be taken seriously and a sequel was made, perhaps Joe would meet the beleaguered geniuses in the sequel. Maybe this movie should be remade as not a dumb comedy.

Comment: Some of them, yes. Tard is implied to be all purpose insult. Somebody has to actually do advanced work in society. There is around 100.000 parts in an airplane and you can't just obey all maintenance procedures and hope everything goes well, there is a certain amount of intelligence and creativity needed. So if there are pilots and drivers, there must be mechanics, air controllers and maintenance crews.

Comment: @jo1storm - In the future airplane maintenance is likely to be automated. The mechanics and controllers don't appear to be doing a great job, as evidenced by the periodic plane crashes

Comment: "jobs (such a pilot)" - running gag as i remember is that things are not what they sound like. Like, the "Time Machine" turns to be not a time machine at all. So maybe pilot here means something else than "21st century-level airplane pilot"

Comment: @jo1storm: If this is so, then perhaps Joe was the rare intelligent person who was recognized as such because he was a stranger. In Kornbluth's The Little Black Bag, the doctors and physicists who are minded by a few geniuses indeed think of these geniuses as dummies.

Comment: I interpreted that scene as the doctor judging him based on his behavior--at this point he still hadn't completely sussed out what happened, let alone how to blend in.

Comment: @Valorum then who is maintaining maintenance robots? Its turtles all the way down!

Comment: @jo1storm - As we see from the maintenance bots at the hospital everything is breaking down ("*Your floor is now clean!"*)